# Event added with addEventListener() isn't fired when triggered by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given this small bit of code:

```
window.addEventListener("test_event", function(e){
    console.log("event fired");
}, false);

console.log("init");

$(window).trigger("test_event");
```

Why isn't the event triggered? Is jQuery doing something behind the scenes that is missed by a standard event handler?

http://jsfiddle.net/Dygerati/zx36aapj/1/

Comment: You might want to read http://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/, *What handlers can be .trigger()'d?*.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking to do is to dispatch a custom event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event("test_event"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zx36aapj/2/

Alternatively - if you can't modify the way the event is triggered you can use `bind` instead:

```
$(window).bind("test_event", function(e){
    console.log("event fired");
});

console.log("init");

$(window).trigger("test_event");
```

Here's a link for that: http://jsfiddle.net/zx36aapj/3/

Comment: Thanks for the response; in my particular scenario I DO have access to the code for the listener, but not for the trigger (which is done by jQuery as outlined). I haven't delved into the code but wouldn't jQuery be creating a custom event behind the scenes? 

What I really need to do is capture the event thrown by jQuery, as opposed to altering how it's triggered.